# In how many ways you can select $6$ letters out of $100$ $A$'s, $80$ $B$'s, $60$ $C$'s,$3$ $D$'s, $2$ $E$'s and $1$ $F$?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I have tried to solve this using cases but I am getting a humongous number of cases that I cant keep track of. Given that its supposed to be solved within $6-8$ minutes, I feel that there must be an easier method that I am missing.

I have solved as follows:
$$(1+x+x^2+x^3...+x^{100})(1+x+x^2+x^3...+x^{80})(1+x+x^2+x^3...+x^
{60})(1+x+x^2+x^3)(1+x+x^2)(1+x)$$
Now I have tried to find the coefficient of $x^6$. But the calculations are absolutely overwhelming here

Comment: This is the same as choosing from 6A's, 6B's 6C's, 3D's, 2E's and 1F.

Comment: I understood that, but still the cases are too high.

Comment: Can you show your work?

Comment: @ArcticChar added my work

Comment: Following @ArcticChar 's comment, and reducing your product likewise, you might also want to reduce $1+x+\cdots +x^6=\frac{1-x^7}{1-x}$. You will get $3$ of these terms, so you will have $\left(\frac{1-x^7}{1-x}\right)^3$ in your product. At this stage use the general form of the binomial theorem, and meanwhile since you just need the sum of coefficients to be $6$, you can always ignore the powers of $x$ that are greater than $6$ in your calculations. So the only term you need from $(1-x^7)^3$ is the $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is same as if you have infinitely many $A,B,C$s

Therefore the generating function is $$({1\over1-x})^3({1-x^4\over 1-x})({1-x^3\over 1-x})({1-x^2\over 1-x})=({1\over1-x})^6(1-x^4)(1-x^3)(1-x^2)$$

$$=({1\over1-x})^6(1-x^2-x^3-x^4+x^5+x^6...)$$ where $...$ represents larger than degree $6$ stuff we don't care.

The coefficient of $1$ in $({1\over1-x})^6$ is $1$

The coefficient of $x$ in $({1\over1-x})^6$ is ${6\choose 5}=6$

The coefficient of $x^2$ in $({1\over1-x})^6$ is ${7\choose 5}=21$

The coefficient of $x^3$ in $({1\over1-x})^6$ is ${8\choose 5}=56$

The coefficient of $x^4$ in $({1\over1-x})^6$ is ${9\choose 5}=126$

The coefficient of $x^6$ in $({1\over1-x})^6$ is ${11\choose 5}=462$

Hence the coefficient of $x^6$ in the final result is $462-126-56-21+6+1=266$

Comment: The infinite approximation seems very helpful. When can we typically assume this to hold and when it would violate ?

Comment: It is actually just a shorthand, if you don't assume the infinity there will be some extra $(1-x^7)$ terms which would be discarded in the final result anyway.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.Its just that finding negative power binomial expansion is slightly tricky for me to remember and thus use in exams.

Comment: It would be helpful to understand that finding $x^n$'s coefficient in $(1+x+x^2+...)^k$ is same as the number of solutions in $a_1+a_2+...+a_k=n$ with non-negative solution, which is same as $a_1+...+a_k=n+k$ with positive solutions, which is same as having $n+k$ balls and put $k-1$ sticks in the $n+k-1$ spaces between balls to separate into $k$ groups.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate solution, not using generating functions.

You can use stars and bars on cases based on $(D,E,F)$

Let $N_k$ be the number of cases requiring $k$ choices from $(A,B,C)$ each of which can be done in $\binom{K+2}2$ ways...

Case $(0,0,0)$
$$ N_6=\binom{ 8 }{2} = 28 $$

Cases $(1,0,0), (0,1,0, (0,0,1)$
$$ N_5=3\binom{ 7 }{2}  =63$$
Cases $(2,0,0) , (0,2,0), (1,1,0), (1, 0,1), (0,1,1)$
$$ N_4=5\binom{ 6 }{2}  =75$$
Cases $(3,0,0) , (2,1,0), (2,0,1),(1,2,0),(1,1,1),(0,2,1)$
$$ N_3=6\binom{ 5 }{2}  =60$$

Cases $(3,1,0), (3,0,1), (2,2,0), (2,1,1) , (1,2,1)$
$$ N_2=5\binom{ 4 }{2}  =30$$
Cases $(3,2,0), (3,1,1), (2,2,1)$
$$ N_1=3\binom{ 3 }{2}  =9$$
Case $(3,2,1)$
$$ N_0=1\binom{ 2 }{2}  =1$$

Now just add them up (getting 266)